# PHP - define static array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

can you initialize a static array of objects in a class in PHP? Like you can do

```
class myclass {
    public static $blah = array("test1", "test2", "test3");
}
```

but when I do

```
class myclass {
    public static $blah2 = array(
        &new myotherclass(),
        &new myotherclass(),
        &new myotherclass()
    );
}
```

where myotherclass is defined right above myclass.
That throws an error however; is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Could you tell us that the error is?

Comment: Set `$blah2` within the constructor. You can't set runtime-calculated values in a property definition.

Comment: @Wiseguy did I get your message right?

Comment: @wiseguy: OP wants a static array - one per class. Initializing it every time you create a new instance seems like a bad approach..

Comment: @user1181950: on an unrelated note, using `new` by reference there has been depreciated for several years now.  Maybe it's slipped under PHP's radar and that's why it still remains to this day without causing a fatal error.  But, just so you know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nope.  From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php:

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed.
>   So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array
>   (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a
>   function return value, or to an object.

I would initialize the property to `null`, make it private with an accessor method, and have the accessor do the "real" initialization the first time it's called. Here's an example:

```
    class myclass {

        private static $blah2 = null;

        public static function blah2() {
            if (self::$blah2 == null) {
               self::$blah2 = array( new myotherclass(),
                 new myotherclass(),
                 new myotherclass());
            }
            return self::$blah2;
        }
    }

    print_r(myclass::blah2());
```

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot initialize it to have these values, you can call a static method to push them into its own internal collection, as I've done below. This may be as close as you'll get.

```
class foo {
  public $bar = "fizzbuzz";
}

class myClass {
  static public $array = array();
  static public function init() {
    while ( count( self::$array ) < 3 )
      array_push( self::$array, new foo() );
  }
}

myClass::init();
print_r( myClass::$array );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/InTPdUCT

Which results in the following output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => foo Object
    (
      [bar] => fizzbuzz
    )
  [1] => foo Object
    (
      [bar] => fizzbuzz
    )
  [2] => foo Object
    (
      [bar] => fizzbuzz
    )
)
```