# how to make static index of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to store values from form radio to array. But problem which i am facing is that every time array 1st index is replaced with new value. I believe this is scope problem. I also tried to declare global array but no success.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$c = new DBcon();
$c->startcon();
global $array; // not effecive
//  $q = $_POST['t'];
//  echo 'fff', $q;


$page = $_GET['page'];
echo 'pagesss', $page, 'ppp';
if ($page == "") {

    $page = "1";
} else {

    // If page is set, let's get it
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// Now lets get all messages from your database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quizes";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

// Lets count all messages
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

// Lets set how many messages we want to display
$per_page = "2";

// Now we must calculate the last page
$last_page = $num;

echo 's', $num;

// And set the first page
$first_page = "1";

// Here we are making the "First page" link
echo "<a href='?page=" . $first_page . "'>First page</a> ";

// If page is 1 then remove link from "Previous" word
if ($page == $first_page) {

    echo "Previous ";
} else {

    if (!isset($page)) {

        echo "Previous ";
    } else {

        // But if page is set and it's not 1.. Lets add link to previous word to take us back by one page
        $previous = $page - 1;

        echo "<a href='?page=" . $previous . "'>Previous</a> ";
    }
}

// If the page is last page.. lets remove "Next" link
if ($page == $last_page) {

    echo "Next ";
} else {

    // If page is not set or it is set and it's not the last page.. lets add link to this word so we can go to the next page
    if (!isset($page)) {

        $next = $first_page + 1;
        echo "<a href='?page=" . $next . "'>Next</a> ";
    } else {

        $next = $page + 1;
        echo "<a href='?page=" . $next . "'>Next</a> ";
    }
}

// And now lets add the "Last page" link
echo "<a href='?page=" . $last_page . "'>Last page</a>";

// Math.. It gets us the start number of message that will be displayed
$start = ($page * ($page - 1)) / $page;
echo 'start', $start;
echo 'page', $page;
// Now lets set the limit for our query
$limit = "LIMIT $start, $per_page";

// It's time for getting our messages
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quizes $limit";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<br /><br />";

// And lets display our messages

$i = 0;
$l = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
    $a = $row['A'];
    echo '<form method="get" action="?page=".$next."">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        echo '<div class="boxed" >';

        echo "\t" . '<tr><th>' .
        $row['question'] . "<br>" .
        '</th><th>' . "<input type='radio' name= 't[]' value='{$row['A']}'>" . $row['A'] . "<br>" .
        '</th><th>' . "<input type='radio' name='t[]' value='{$row['B']}'>" . $row['B'] . "<br>" .
        '</th><th>' . "<input type='radio' name='t[]' value='{$row['C']}'>" . $row['C'] . "<br>" .
        '</th><th>' . "<input type='radio' name='t[]' value='{$row['D']}'>" . $row['D'] . '</th>
                </tr>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="' . $next . '">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
        $i++;

        echo '</div>';


        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</form>';
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $example = $_GET['t'];
        foreach ($example as $value) {
            $array[$i++] = ($value);

            echo "$array[0] <br>"; // printing correct statement but replacing old values with new value everytime.
            echo "$array[1] <br>"; // 0 values
            echo "$array[2] <br>"; // 0 values
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have seen these posts: [PHP array indexing: $array[$index] vs $array["$index"] vs $array["{$index}"]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628/php-array-indexing-arrayindex-vs-arrayindex-vs-arrayindex) , [PHP - define static array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771502/php-define-static-array-of-objects) but no help. Kindly help what should i do?

Comment: One thing, instead of doing a mysql_row_count at the beginning just do a query like: `"SELECT count(*) FROM quizes"` since it will only return one value, otherwise you transfer more data than necessary to get the same value from the database.  Second do a var_dump of the $example value to see what you get as a response to your form.

Comment: u mean i shd add extra query?

Comment: var_dump yeah but i am unable to add values in array. Instead it is only adding and replacing value on 1st index not on others.

Comment: Make sure you print out the $i value too in the loop to be sure that it is setting the value correctly.

Comment: i have written count query in this way:  
$count = "SELECT count(*) FROM quizes ";
    $cnt = mysql_query($count);
    echo 'count',$cnt;

is it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand... are you trying to get multiple values from a set of RADIO button options ? Isn't the point of the radio button to return only one value from the set ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do

```
$array[$i++]
```

this will always be $array[1]
instead do

```
$i++;
$array[$i]= $value;
```

P.S. $array is a terrible name for a variable...

Comment: i did but value is storing in the 1st index and replacing old value with new in 1st index

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $example = $_GET['t'];
$i=0;
$arrayA = array();
        foreach ($example as $value) {
            $arrayA[$i] = ($value);
$i++;

        }
print_r($arrayA);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must increment your variable first, then use the variable as the array key.

Edit: this is what you're looking for:

```
$i = 0; 

foreach ($example as $value) {
    $array[$i] = $value;    

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: how? is nt like c++?

Comment: actually $i++ does not return true, it returns $i. $i=10; var_dump($i++) will output 10 not true

Comment: same nothing change. If u see my code:-  if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
     $l++;
     $example = $_GET['t'];
     foreach ($example as $value) {
     
      $array[$l] = ($value);
      
      echo 'l',$l,"$array[$l] <br>";
      $l++;
      
     } they all are in 1st while loop and as a result i am stuck in scope and thats why i am unable to add values in array, Can u suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
$array[$i++] ;
```

it wont work , just try this and it wont replace your old value

```
$array[$i] = $value;    

    $i++;
```