# PHP: show random images from folder without repeat

Tags: php, image

I have approximately 20-25 images in my folder.

I have PHP script, that choose and show random image. But problem is that some images have been showed repeatedly, while some others have not been showed even once.

How to display all images in a randomly choice manner?

Thanks!

Comment: please show us the code u tried.

Comment: What should I show ? It's just a random image picking from image. That's simple then why r  u asking for code ?

Comment: if you can not show your code than what you want that we should code for you?

Answer (score 0):

Do next steps:
1) Take some random image
2) Add this image's name to some array
3) Randomly choose one more image and, if this image is already exists in your array, choose another image randomly.

Comment: @johnjosh you may create a static array

Comment: @johnjosh create static array, then do that 3 steps. And all images have been showed already, clean the array

Comment: How to create static array ? I'm not using OOP approach. @Khazratbek

Comment: @johnjosh in asp.net or php?

Comment: I'm using php sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771502/php-define-static-array-of-objects take it as example) @johnjosh